# requiring files in ruby and errors

Tags: ruby, rspec

I was wondering if someone could help clarify the differences between require and require relative and help explain the problems here. My file structure is

```
spec/
  lion_spec.rb
  panda_spec.rb
lib/
  lion.rb
  panda.rb
  animal.rb
```

In order to keep the code dry I created an `Animal` class. My problem is since doing so, I am getting an rspec error:

```
uninitialized constant Animal (NameError)
```

I know this generally means I have not required something properly or created the class but i can't seem to find this and now i am getting n a mess with the requires!

**lion_spec**

```
require 'animal'
require 'lion'

describe Lion do 
    it "should like wildebeests" do 
        expect(Lion.new.likes?(:wildebeests)).to eq(true)
    end

    it "should like zebras" do
    expect(Lion.new.likes?(:zebras)).to eq(true) 
    end

    it "should not like salad" do 
        expect(Lion.new.likes?(:salad)).to eq(false)
    end
end
```

**panda_spec**

```
require 'animal'
require 'panda'

describe Panda do 

    it 'should like bamboo' do 
        expect(Panda.new.likes?(:bamboo)).to eq(true)   
    end

    it 'should like bamboo as a string' do 
        expect(Panda.new.likes?("bamboo")).to eq(true)
    end

    it 'should not like grasshoppers' do 
        expect(Panda.new.likes?("grasshoppers")).to eq(false)
    end
end
```

**lion.rb**

```
require 'animal'

class Lion < Animal

    def acceptable_food
        [:wildebeests, :zebras]
    end
end
```

**panda.rb**

```
require 'animal'

class Panda < Animal

    def acceptable_food
        [:bamboo]
    end
end
```

**animal.rb**

```
require 'animal'

class Panda < Animal

    def acceptable_food
        [:bamboo]
    end
end
```

for test coverage to be good i amended to the following:

```
**lion_spec**
require 'animal'
require 'lion'


describe Lion do 
    it "should like wildebeests" do 
        expect(Lion.new.likes?(:wildebeests)).to eq(true)
    end

    it "should like zebras" do
    expect(Lion.new.likes?(:zebras)).to eq(true) 
    end

    it "should not like salad" do 
        expect(Lion.new.likes?(:salad)).to eq(false)
    end
end
```

**panda_spec**
    require 'animal'
    require 'panda'

```
describe Panda do 

    it 'should like bamboo' do 
        expect(Panda.new.likes?(:bamboo)).to eq(true)   
    end

    it 'should like bamboo as a string' do 
        expect(Panda.new.likes?("bamboo")).to eq(true)
    end

    it 'should not like grasshoppers' do 
        expect(Panda.new.likes?("grasshoppers")).to eq(false)
    end
end 

**lion.rb**
require 'animal'


class Lion < Animal

    def acceptable_food
        [:wildebeests, :zebras]
    end
end

**panda.rb**
require 'animal'

class Panda < Animal

    def acceptable_food
        [:bamboo]
    end
end

**animal.rb**
class Animal
        def likes?(food)
        acceptable_food.include?(food.to_sym)
    end
end
```

Comment: I think the snippet for `animal.rb` is wrong.

Comment: can you clarify how you think animal.rb s wrong?

Comment: because it shows the contents of `panda.rb` :)

Comment: also can you maybe the complete output of rspec? I tested your code and it works as a charm

Comment: could you possibly tell me what you did for it to work. I created a spec helper file with the require paths you suggested and it did not work but with the following it now works but i am feeling unsure as to whether i am testing the right things? panda_spec: requires animal and panda.rb files, lion_spec: requires lion and animal.rb files, lion and panda.rb files require animal and finally animal requires nothing currently?

Comment: What is the precise error message you are getting? Which line of which file does it occur on? I concur with @Manuel, I copy&pasted your code, and it works fine.

Comment: thanks it is working fine for me now too since cleaning up the requires

Comment: i am getting the same error lib/panda.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Animal (NameError)

Comment: the code works fine if i remove certain requires but surely the animal.rb file needs to require lion and panda